# Show that $F = \int_0^x f(t)dt $ is bijective function from $ [0,1]$ to $[0,A]$

Tags: analysis

> Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a continuous function and $f > 0$. Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt $ and let $F(1)=A$.
>
> **1**. Show that $F$ is bijective function from $ [0,1]$ to $[0,A]$.
>
> **2**. Show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^* $, there is a unique subdivision: $x_0 = 0 < x_1 < ... < x_{x-1} < x_n = 1 $, such that for $ k=0,1,..., n-1 $, we have: $\int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}} f(t)dt = \frac{A}{n}$.
>
> **3**. Show that $F^{-1} (\frac{kA}{n}) = x_{k+1}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_{k}) = \frac{1}{A} \int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^2 dx. $

**My work.**

**1**. To show $F$ is bijective, I need to show it is injective and surjective, which I don't know how to do for this function.

**2**. $ A = \int_{0}^1f(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}} f(x)dx $.

I don't see how to proceed to get $\int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}} f(t)dt = \frac{A}{n}$.

**3**. $F$ is bijective, so it has an inverse function.

From question **2**, $F^{-1}(\frac{kA}{n}) = F^{-1}\big(k \int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}} f(t)dt \big)$ I don't see how to get $x_{k+1}$ from that.

For the limit, I tried to use Riemann sums but I got stuck too. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), note that $F$ is continuous and moreover $F'(x)=f(x)>0$ so $F$ is also strictly monotone. Hence $F$ is injective and by the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) $F$ attains all the values between $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=A$.

As regards (2), by the bijectivity for any $0\leq k\leq n$ there is a unique $x_k\in [0,1]$ such that $F(x_k)=\frac{kA}{n}$.
Hence
$$\int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}} f(t)dt =F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)=\frac{(k+1)A}{n}-\frac{kA}{n}= \frac{A}{n}.$$

Finally for (3), we have use Riemann sums,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_{k})  =\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(F^{-1}(kA/n))\\=\frac{1}{A} \int_{0}^{A}(f(F^{-1}(t))) dt
=\frac{1}{A} \int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^2 dx.$$
where $t=F(x)$, $dt=f(x) dx$.

Comment: That proves it is injective. What about surjective? Thank you.

Comment: @Jacon See my edited answer.

Comment: $F$ is continuous because $F' = f$ is continuous too?

Comment: $f$ is bounded and integrable which  implies that the integral function $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Could  you please explain to me how $F(x_{k}) = \frac{kA}{n}$. I mean $F$ is bijective and for $ y \in [0, A]$ there is $x_{k} \in [0,1]$ such that $F(x_{k}) = y$, but why is $y = \frac{kA}{n}$. Thank you.

Comment: For each $k$ we take $\frac{kA}{n}\in[0,A]$ and find $x_k=F^{-1}(\frac{kA}{n})$. Such $x_k$ exists by bijectivity of $F$ and $x_k<x_{k+1}$ because $F$ is strictly monotone

Comment: Yes please. How did you get $\frac{1}{A} \int_{0}^{A}(f(F^{-1}(t))) dt$ ? Using the Riemann sums the limit would be $ \int_{0}^{1} f(F^{-1}(Ax))dx$ and taking $ y = Ax $, we'll have $dy = Adx$ and we get $ I = A \int_{0}^{A} f(F^{-1}(y))dy $. How to proceed to get the final limit? Thank you.

Comment: For the RS the division points are $kA/n$ of the interval $[0,A]$. You are also correct but in the final step $dx$ becomes $dy/A$ (not $Ady$). For the final limit make the substitution $t=F(x)$. Hence $dt=F'(x)dx=f(x)dx.$

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help.